# AssertionError trying to check dashboard URL is opened after login

Tags: java, selenium, assert, assertions

I am new in selenium, I try to login and check if dashboard URL is opened, but java.lang.AssertionError appears every-time. Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong. I try to compare if current URL that is supposed to be my dashboard URL equals to expURL. here is my code:

```
//test  
    @Test
    public static void LoginPage(){
        PageLogin loginPage = new PageLogin(driver);

        driver.get("http://37.252.65.134:8885/#/core/login");

        loginPage.enterCredentials("Apollo", "123");

        loginPage.clickOnLogin();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        result = PageLogin.validateURL(driver,"http://37.252.65.134:8885/#/app/dashboard");
        Assert.assertTrue(result);   
        }   

//page object 

package LoginPage;

public class PageLogin {
   WebDriver driver;

  //locators

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[contains(@type,'text')]")
   private WebElement username;

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[contains(@type,'password')]")
   private WebElement password;

   @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//button[contains(.,'login')]")
   private WebElement loginbutton;


   //Constructor
   public PageLogin(WebDriver driver){
       this.driver = driver;

         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
   }

   public void enterCredentials(String username, String password){
       this.username.clear();
       this.username.sendKeys(username);

       this.password.clear();
       this.password.sendKeys(password);           
   }

   public void clickOnLogin(){

       this.loginbutton.click();

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }

    public static boolean validateURL (WebDriver driver, String expURL) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(expURL))
        {
            result = true;
            System.out.println("Login Success");                        
        }
                return result;          
    }   
}
```

Comment: It looks like your expected URL is not the same as URL you are getting, that's why assertion error is thrown. Which URL are you getting in your validateURL method?

Comment: Probably the method `validateURL ()` still getting the login URL at `driver.getCurrentUrl()`. All you have to do is wait for your dashboard to be fully loaded. You can do it by using explicity waiting like `WebDriverWait`. You can try to fix it by adding this code before comparing the URLs `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf (loginButton));`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to do that

Comment: @Renato, Now it gives another error: Unable to locate element: //button[contains(.,'login')], 
but I think the problem is that stalenessOf is not recognized, it says "This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

Comment: @TatevikMelikyan try to use this piece of code right after click at login button. If still not working, use another condition from `ExpectedConditions` class to wait for an element from dashboard page, otherwise, post what URL you're getting from `driver.getCurrentUrl()` at the comparision moment.

Comment: @Renato Thanks a lot it worked, i used this expected condition wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("")));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
java.lang.AssertionError
```

The error must have been diagnosed much before as your program is not printing **Login Success** as per the line :

```
System.out.println("Login Success");
```

The main reason is *Synchronization Issue* and as the condition of `if()` doesn't satisfies and **`result = false`** is returned.

### Solution

The solution would be to wait for the **`getCurrentUrl()`** to contain/tobe/match **`http://37.252.65.134:8885/#/app/dashboard`**. To achieve that you can use either of the clauses from [*ExpectedConditions*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) of [*WebDriverWait*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) options as follows :

- [*`urlContains(java.lang.String fraction)`*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlContains-java.lang.String-)

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("37.252.65.134:8885"));
  ```
- [*`urlToBe(java.lang.String url)`*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlToBe-java.lang.String-)

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("http://37.252.65.134:8885/#/app/dashboard"));
  ```
- [*`urlMatches(java.lang.String regex)`*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlMatches-java.lang.String-)

Once the new `url` is established then you can validate the result in a `for()` loop as :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("37.252.65.134:8885"));
if (driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(expURL))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, i used this expected condition wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("")));